# How to ContourPlot a two variables (x,y) implicit function with y normalized?

Tags: plotting, implicit

I am trying to use `ContourPlot` to plot an implicit function.
Now I have two variables (x,y) implicit function:

```
(b x)/a + y == ((c + d) Log[1 - (n y)/(c + d)])/m
```

where `b/a=0.0065`,`c+d=-3276.26` and `n=9770.6`, `m=9770.6`， `x{0,60}`. I can `ContourPlot` it `y~x` correctly. Physically, `x` is the time, `y` is the distance.

Actually, the `y` has the region `{0,k}`, now I want to `ContourPlot` it with `y` normalized, i.e. the `x`-axis is the time, `y`-axis is the distance `y` divided by `k` (`y/k`), ranges from 0 to 1. Just like this
[image: "the plot result"]

Comment: "a,b,c,d,m and n are all known", But I do not know anything about them ?

Comment: I have updated the parameters in the equation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using your numbers the expression `((c + d) Log[1 - (n y)/(c + d)])/m` results in an imaginary number whenever `y` is greater than approximately 0.4. One is unable to plot imaginary numbers directly with `Plot` or `ContourPlot`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since the scaling is linear, you can simply relabel the ticks:

```
k = 3;
ContourPlot[x - y^2, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, k}, 
  Contours -> {{1, Red}, {2, Green}, {3, Blue}, {4, Purple}}, 
  ContourShading -> None, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Charting`FindTicks[{0, k}, {0, 1}], Automatic},     Automatic}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, multiply all `y`s by `k` in the first argument of `ContourPlot` and use `{y, 0, 1}` for the y range:

```
ContourPlot[x - (k y)^2, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  Contours -> {{1, Red}, {2, Green}, {3, Blue}, {4, Purple}}, 
  ContourShading -> None ]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thank you for your help!